# Codeblocks(IDE) with debugger from VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, codeblocks

How can I plug debugger from VS to Code::Blocks?
Really couldn't find anything on the web.

Comment: @Mat VS compiler is of poor quality.

Comment: @Mat poor C++11 support compared to gcc, that's the problem I have with VS.

Comment: @Mat it is of poor quality in sense of C++11 conforming.

Comment: If you guys want to continue discussing VS/GCC, please take it to chat.

Comment: @Mat fair enough. Anyway returning to my question, is there a way to use vs debugger with cb?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the code block (`<%%>`) in Visual Studio and press <kbd>F9</kbd> on your keyboard to insert a breakpoint.

Comment: I think the question is about integration the Visual Studio debugger in the `code::blocks` IDE.

Comment: @Mat - possibly. That's now how I read it. However, the OP didn't really give enough detail to figure out which one of us is right.